# How to set focus on text box whenever it appears on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've made a web application That starts from a specific amount and every time a donation is made it counts down and shows how much is needed. And at one time I might have about 10-20 of these counting down and I am always creating new ones. Now when I am doing that it would be nice that when I click the button it automatically focuses on the text field for ease of use. however I can't quite get that to work.

The window to set the countdown is shown using angularjs dialogs/modals. This means that when I click the a button it writes code onto the page that shows the dialog/modal and when I submit it it is removed from the page completely.

The first time around when I click the button it focuses on the text box and I can type the number and press enter and it's submitted, now I want to create a new one. I click the button, up comes the modal but now I have to grab the mouse, move it to the input and click it. Waste of time and not user friendly.

What I'm asking is for a way to have it focus on the text field when using modals every time I click the button.

here's the window:

```
    <form name="formCountdown" novalidate class="css-form">
    <div modal="showCountdownModal" close="showCountdownModal = false" options="opts" ng-cloak>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4>Enter Countdown Amount</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input id="focusbox" type="number" min="1" autofocus required ng-model="countDownAmount" name="countDownAmount" ui-keypress="{13:'setCountdown()'}" select-on-focus />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary cancel" ng-disabled="formCountdown.$invalid" ng-click="setCountdown()">Set</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

I've tried using autofocus, and that works fine the first time you press the button after loading the page. but the second and up it does not.
I've also tried using this jquery code with no luck:

```
<script>
$("#focusbtn").click(function() {
    $("#focusbox").focus();
});
</script>
```

And now I am completely lost and would really love it if someone could help me out here.

Comment: You miss a dot symbol in focus event. What do you means with autofocus? Focus onload or focus onclick?

Comment: That dot was there before, I was trying some different ways of getting it to work. So even adding the dot in won't help. and with autofocus I mean adding autofocus as one of the input field properties.

Comment: If you want to setfocus when enter button is pressed just use keydown event. I'll try to demonstrate my answer below.

Comment: Or maybe you forgot to add $(document).ready(function(){/*Code onload*/});

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not working for you. I think you must declare $(document).ready(); first before button click event.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your posted code together with the script and it works just fine. I'm not sure if I understood the problem but the autofocus works well in my end. Autofocus is present after the page has loaded or refreshed and even after the button has been clicked. Of course the autofocus will be removed if a click outside the input text has been triggered.

Morever, I think Autofocus is an attribute by HTML5. You might want to include  in your HTML or maybe it is just a browser compatibility issue. 
You can test or check if autofocus is supported by your browser at http://html5test.com/.

Hope this help somehow.

EDIT:

Try this on your script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".modalName").on('shown', function() {
    $(this).find("[autofocus]:first").focus(); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: When I click the button to show that modal, the first time around it will focus, the second third, fourth so on and so forth, it will not work.

Comment: Please try this code on your script
`$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modalName").on('shown', function() {
        $(this).find("[autofocus]:first").focus();
    });
});`
* Please add also a class name for your <div modal...>

Answer (score 0):

Edit: forgot to put in the timeout, to make sure the browser is ready!

add the following line to your setCountDown() function:

```
$timeout(function (){
     document.querySelector('#focusbox').focus();
},0)
```

You need to inject the $timeout in your controller
That will probably do the trick!
However, this will work, but dom manipulation should be done in a directive!

Comment: This is not going to work. when the countdown is set, it closes the window so I can set a new countdown for something different.

Comment: Hmm, So your windows is destroyed and rebuild on every entry? 
My code might still work when you put in a longer timeout, but that's a bit of a hacky solution.

Comment: yes, it's removed completely when you close it and then rebuilt when you click the button to set a new countdown.

Comment: @KristoferAronSverrisson then you can add the code to the click function of the button that opens the the window.